# C# and casting generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, types, casting

I'm coming from C++ template programming and get very confused with generics sometimes. As there is no method specialization, I tried using casting. Here's what I have:

```
public interface INonGen
{
    void Get<T>(ref T value);
}

public interface IGen<U> : INonGen
{

}

public class Gen<U> : IGen<U>
{
    private U u;
    public void Get<T>(ref T value)
    {
        if (value is U)
        {
            value = (T) u;
        }         
        else
            throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile.

Is there I way I can make this cast?

The reason why I want this: With C++ templates, I would have made specializations for the types supported, and a non-specialied version that throws an exception.

The basic idea is this: A non-generic interface that has a generic method. Attempts to get the value using the correct type should work, attempts to use the wrong type can throw.

We should keep type safety, so I need to return an instance/value of the correct type. Any shortcuts over object are not acceptable, and neither is constraining the type in the non-generic interface.

The generic implementation is done to avoid duplication. I want to support multiple different types (but only a small set of types), but I want this to be decided when I instantiate a class (and define what T means); I still want the non-generic interface to allow access using any T; that is, I don't want the set of types explicitly in the interface.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there's a better way than your current approach.

Comment: While templating, like in C++ seems like it saves you work, really it defies static analysis and pushes your work into the future when you'll have less time and more pressure. Use your type safety to your advantage and find the problems early.

Comment: @Jodrell that doesn't help. With specializations, I could easily make a few Get<double>, Get<ISomething> implementations and throw otherwise. I would like a way to have similar functionality in C#.

Comment: @Wilbert, what do you do with the exceptions, when `T` is uncatered for?

Comment: @Jodrell Not part of the problem here, I guess, but ok: Dict<SomeKey, INonGen>; I look up the key and want to get the value from the resulting repo. The exception is thrown when a key is matched to the wrong type; so that's ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you cast an object to another, if the compiler can't find a conversion, it reports an error. Since the two type parameters are unconstrained, the only option is to use the `as` operator, which, instead of throwing an `InvalidCastException`, returns `null` when the cast fails. To use `as` you also need to constrain your generic type to classes.

```
public class Gen<U> : IGen<U>
{
    private U u;
    public void Get<T>(ref T value)
            where T : class
    {
        if (value is U)
        {
            value = u as T;
        }         
        else
            throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

If you don't want to add the constraint, you can cast to `Object`:

```
value = (T)(object)u;
```

There's a logical error in your code though. If `value is U`, what guarantees that `u is T`? For example:

```
 var gen = new Gen<Base>();
 gen.Set(new DerivedA()); // sets u;
 var b = new DerivedB();
 gen.Get(ref b);
```

In this case `value is Base` but **not** `u is DerivedB`. The cast will fail at runtime.

**Update**

After reading some of your comments, here's how I would've designed this:

```
public interface INonGen
{
    object Value { get; }
}

public interface IGen<U> : INonGen
{
}

public class Gen<U> : IGen<U>
{
    private U u;
    public object Value
    {
       get { return u; }
    }
}
```

And when pulling items out of the dictionary:

```
double value = (double)dictionary[key].Value;
```

An `InvalidCastException` will be thrown if there's no runtime conversion. Simple, no?

Comment: But then you give up type safety.

Comment: Hm, indeed. Intuitively, I don't like the answer, but it solves my problem.

Comment: @Wilbert: What you are describing in the comment on my answer is runtime type checking. That is why you don't like it. Can you explain why you want the method to be callable with any T?

Comment: @MikeGoodwin It's the inner part of a lookup. I have (app-wide) a set of unique keys that map to values or instances; I look up the non-generic repo from a Dict<MyKey, INonGen>, then I want to get the value or instance. I want the single dict for all keys-to-repo lookups, and it's ok if the non-matching type excepts because then there's an error in the logic of the caller.

Comment: @EliArbel Just read your updated answer: No, because in this case, the caller does not need to specify the type. I want the caller to call Get<TheTypeTheCallerExpects>, not object get.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the purpose of `INonGen` is in this context, especially as it has a generic method. If you get rid of that you can do this. Which compiles - I checked ;o)

```
public interface IGen<T>
{
    void Get(ref T value);
}

public class Gen<T, U> : IGen<T> where U : T
{
    private U u;

    public void Get(ref T value) 
    {
        if (value is U)
        {
            value = (T)u;
        }
        else
            throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

The point is that you cannot have the generic type argument on the interface method only, because that prevents you from specifying the  `U : T` constraint in the implementing class. It has to be on the interface definition itself. And the implementing class has to know explicitly about both generic type arguments `U` and `T`, so that the compiler can verify the cast operation.

You could go down the route of using `as` but this is not type safe, so you have to handle cases where the result is `null`, rather than relying on the compiler to do it. Not recommended.

If in your real world example, `INonGen` has other non-generic methods, or generic methods where implementing classes *do not need to know about the method's generic type arguments outside of the implementing method* then you could reinstate it without any problems.

```
public interface INonGen
{
    void NonGenericMethod();
    void GenericMethod<V>(V parameter);
}

public interface IGen<T> : INonGen
{
    void Get(ref T value);
}

public class Gen<T, U> : IGen<T> where U : T
{
    private U u;

    public void Get(ref T value) 
    {
        if (value is U)
        {
            value = (T)u;
        }
        else
            throw new Exception();
    }

    public void NonGenericMethod()
    {
    }

    public void GenericMethod<V>(V parameter)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll never get to the exception in the first example, the code wouldn't compile.

Comment: I want the Get<T> from the non-generic interface to be callable using any T; but only calls where T is U should succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a concept call [constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) ...

```
public class Gen<U> : IGen<U> where U : T
{
    private U u;
    public void Get<T>(ref T value)
    {
        if (value is U)
        {
            value = (T) u;
        }         
        else
            throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

This tells you that `U` must be or derive from the argument supplied for `T`.

Comment: It still doesn't build. Gives an error `The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Despite the idea is here (using constraints), it cannot compile: the T generic type needs to be known in the main class definition.

Comment: The generic class must accept any T, but only cast/return a value when T matches U.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `ref` for this either. Then your problem becomes moot.

```
public interface IThing
{
    object Value { get; }
}

public interface IThing<T> : IThing
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public class Thing<T> : IThing<T>
{
    private T t;

    public object Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Get();
        }
    }

    public T Value<T>()
    {
        get
        {
            return this.t;
        }
    }
}
```

If you really want to accept some generic other, that is constrained to the right type

```
public interface ICrazyThing<T>
{
    void Get<T>(ref T crazy);
}

public class CrazyThing<U, T> : IThing<T> where T : U
{
    private U u;

    public void Get<T>(ref T crazy)
    {
       crazy = this.u;   
    }
}
```

Even in crazy world, `out` would be a better choice than `ref`, since the value passed in is a pointless instantiation that has no bearing on the result.

Comment: out is the same as ref internally (and also in C++/Cli), but I can do more type determination on it that on out params before explicit initialization.

Comment: @Wilbert, sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "more type determination".